# Regular expression to match time and IRC-Nick

Tags: php, regex, irc

I'm not very experienced in regular expressions and I tried a lot to match a string like this:

```
16:02 &lt;DJ_Bjarne&gt;
```

with a regex, but I didn't get any working result.
I want this to be replaced by

```
<strong>16:02&lt;DJ_Bjarne&gt;</strong>
```

with a regex that works in PHP.
Thank you.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far so people can help you fix them.

Comment: Please edit your post: do _not_ use html encoding. Just paste your examples and regex as the are, then select the whole line(s) and use the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post = "16:02 &lt; DJ_Bjarne&gt; hello mate!";
preg_replace("/(.*?&gt;)/", "<strong>$1</strong>", $post);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} <.*?>/', '<strong>$0</strong>', $string);
```

Comment: $0 refers to the whole string that matched. $1 refers to the first parenthesized group. In your case, this is the same thing, since you wrapped all the regex in a bracket. In my case, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/[\d]{2}:[\d]{2} [\<][\w]+[\>]/', '<strong>${0}</strong>', $line)
```

Comment: How is this a comment? I'm giving him the way to replace a nick string with what he wanted. Is this not what he was asking?

Answer (score 0):

y Tooo complecated

```
$text  = '16:02 &lt;DJ_Bjarne&gt;';
echo $text = preg_replace("/\A/",'<strong>',$text);
//echo "<textarea>";echo $text;echo "</textarea>";
$text = preg_replace("/\Z/",'</strong>',$text);
echo "<textarea>";echo $text;echo "</textarea>";
```

its simple easy to understand, [refference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)